# Edit a WPF datagrid cell using buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have replicated numeric keys as buttons in a WPF window. Now I want to edit the Selected WPF datagrid cell with those button. How can I get the focused cell and replace the field value with button click?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into DataTemplates with a combination of EventTriggers or similar to do this.